# Exceeded quota for tabledata.list bytes per second

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am firing a set of queries on tables in BigQuery dataset.

There are 3 `select *` queries as below:

```
"Select * from table1"    //1.3M records and 2.5GB data
"Select * from table2"      //0.3M records and 15 GB data
"Select * from table3"     //2M    records and 3GB data
```

We are querying the above tables using the spark connector. However intermittently we are seeing an error:

> 403 Forbidden"
>   "domain" : "usageLimits",
>   message: " "message" : "Exceeded rate limits: Your project:  exceeded quota for tabledata.list bytes per second per project.

The assumption here is that the tabledata list call is failing because it is returning more than 60 MB per sec which seems to be the default quota as per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

Comment: That's not an assumption, that's a fact. Slow down to do not reach the limit.

Comment: @Pentium10 Is this a soft limit or hard limit on the BigQuery side? I am not able to find this information in the documentation. If it is a soft limit, I think increasing the quota is an option?

Comment: Since the Ops question please use and refer to Storage API, it was engineered for this large scale reads https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage

Answer (score 3):

Tabledata.list isn't really optimized for high-throughput use cases such as Spark. You may want to check out other options for reading from BigQuery -- in particular, this use case is what the [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/) is designed for, including a [native Spark connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector).