# How to iterate Big Query TableResult correctly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I have a complex join query in Big Query and need to run in a spark job. This is the current code:

```
val bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(bigQueryConfig.bigQueryProjectId)
      .setCredentials(credentials)
      .build().getService

val query =
      //some complex query

val queryConfig: QueryJobConfiguration =
      QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
        query)
        .setUseLegacySql(false)
        .setPriority(QueryJobConfiguration.Priority.BATCH) //(tried with and without)
        .build()

val jobId: JobId = JobId.newBuilder().setRandomJob().build()

val queryJob: Job = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build).waitFor()

val result = queryJob.getQueryResults()

val output = result.iterateAll().iterator().asScala.to[Seq].map { row: FieldValueList =>

//create case class from the row
}
```

It keeps running into this error:

> Exceeded rate limits: Your project: XXX exceeded quota for tabledata.list bytes per second per project.

Is there a way to better iterate through the results? I have tried to do `setPriority(QueryJobConfiguration.Priority.BATCH)` on the query job configuration, but it doesn't improve results. Also tried to reduce the number of spark executors to 1, but of no use.

Comment: Setting `BATCH` won't help. It does something different than you think (it places your initial query in a lower priority queue rather than executing it immediately i.e. it's the opposite of an `INTERACTIVE` query). Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510164/exceeded-quota-for-tabledata-list-bytes-per-second and here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#api_requests for better reading of tables/rows over the wire.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The documentation mentions how to read from BQ table, but not queries. Also, BigQuery Storage API requests
The following limits apply to ReadRows calls using the BigQuery Storage API:

ReadRows calls per minute: 5,000 : When you read data using the BigQuery Storage API, you are limited to 5,000 ReadRows calls per minute, per user, per project.
The following limits apply to all other method calls using the BigQuery Storage API:

API calls per minute: 1,000 : You are limited to 1,000 BigQuery Storage API calls per minute, per user, per project.

Comment: Every query is a table. When you run a query in BigQuery, its results are saved as a temp table under the hood if you don't specify the table destination to write the results to. You need to adhere to the limits/quotas i.e. slow down your requests.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the query results directly, you can use the [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector) to read them into a DataFrame:

```
val queryConfig: QueryJobConfiguration =
      QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
        query)
        .setUseLegacySql(false)
        .setPriority(QueryJobConfiguration.Priority.BATCH) //(tried with and without)
        .setDestinationTable(TableId.of(destinationDataset, destinationTable))
        .build()
val jobId: JobId = JobId.newBuilder().setRandomJob().build()

val queryJob: Job = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build).waitFor()

val result = queryJob.getQueryResults()

// read into DataFrame
val data = spark.read.format("bigquery")
  .option("dataset",destinationDataset)
  .option("table" destinationTable)
  .load()
```

Comment: Thanks David Rabinowitz for your response. I intend to use this, but running to issues while adding spark bigquery dependencies on my project. It throws a ClassNotFoundException on my main class when the spark job is submitted. Im trying to resolve that. Will update on how it goes

Comment: Do you know if we can directly execute a bigquery query using spark-bigquery connector instead of execute query -> store to intermediate table -> read from table

Comment: Regarding the ClassNotFoundException - please have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector) on how to add the connector to your project. In a nutshell you can add a --jars parameter to your spark-submit. Regarding your second issue, notice that BigQuery is not a usual database, and it will store the query results in a temporary table anyway, so doing so does not change the usual behavior.

Comment: I have to read close to 100 large BQ tables and its taking a very long time. As per my original code, the query was executed in the executors. But now because spark session is used to read, its run in the driver and is just too slow

Comment: Are you sure it's the reading part or the queries? What is the size of the results? I can assure you that getQueryResults runs in a single thread, while the Spark DataSource API (underlying spark.read) distribute the read to the executors. Have you ran the original code as part of a lambda on the executors?

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the situation by providing a custom page size on the TableResult