# How to use Spark BigQuery connector to join multiple tables and then fetch the data into dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I have to read three different bigquery tables and then join them to get some data which will be stored to GCS bucket. I was using Spark BQ connector.

```
# Load data from BigQuery.
bqdf = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
    .option('table', bq_dataset + bq_table) \
    .load()
bqdf.createOrReplaceTempView('bqdf')
```

This reads entire table data to dataframe. I know that I can apply filter on tables and also select required columns. Thereafter create three dataframes and then join them to get the output.

Is there any equivalent way to achieve this?

I have an option of using BigQuery client API (https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html) and import it from pyspark script. However, if I can achive that through Spark BQ connector, dont want to use the API call from python script.

Please help.

Comment: Hi! Do you run Spark on Dataproc cluster?

Comment: Yes. I am running pyspark on Dataproc

Comment: The way you are trying to achieve it is the recommended way. As an addition you can take a look to another SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581485/how-to-iterate-big-query-tableresult-correctly) and official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example#pyspark).